# python compare values of the sublists of a list and add up values

Tags: python, list

I have a list with an unknown number of sublists. 
I want to compare always one sublist with **ALL** other sublists. 
If the values of the first sublist at position 0, 3 and 5 are equal to any other sublist, I want to to add together the values at position 7 in all matching lists. 
And then add this first sublist with the (newly added up value) at position 7 to a new list.

```
list = [['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '1'], 
         ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '3'], 
         ['D', 'r', 's', 'E', 't', 'u', 'F', '2'], 
         ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '2'], 
         ['D', 'r', 's', 'E', 't', 'u', 'F', '2'],.....]
```

wanted Output:

```
new_list = [['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '6'], 
             ['D', 'r', 's', 'E', 't', 'u', 'F', 4],...]
```

I wrote this code

```
def Inter(list):
a = 0
b = 3 
c = 5 
d = 0
x = [] 

for i in range(len(list)): 
    for y in range(len(list)):
        if list[i][a] == list[y][a] and list[i][b] == list[y][b] and list[i][c] == list[y][c]: 
            IntSumtemp = []
            IntSumtemp.append(str(float(list[i][7]) + float(list[y][7])))
            x.append(list[i] + IntSumtemp) 
            del (x[d][7])
            d +=1
        else: None
return x
new_list= Inter(list)
```

but it gave this output:

```
new_list= [['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '2.0'], 
       ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '4.0'], 
       ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '3.0'], 
       ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '4.0'], 
       ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '6.0'], 
       ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '5.0'], 
       ['D', 'r', 's', 'E', 't', 'u', 'F', '4.0'], 
       ['D', 'r', 's', 'E', 't', 'u', 'F', '4.0'], 
       ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '3.0'], 
       ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '5.0'], 
       ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '4.0'], 
       ['D', 'r', 's', 'E', 't', 'u', 'F', '4.0'],
       ['D', 'r', 's', 'E', 't', 'u', 'F', '4.0']]
```

Can someone help me with this, please? 
(Sorry, I am a absolute beginner, so if anything is unclear, plz ask...)

Answer (score 1):

This approach is O(N) as opposed to yours which was O(N^2)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from operator import itemgetter

items = [['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '1'], 
         ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '3'], 
         ['D', 'r', 's', 'E', 't', 'u', 'F', '2'], 
         ['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', '2'], 
         ['D', 'r', 's', 'E', 't', 'u', 'F', '2']]


key = itemgetter(0, 3, 5)
d = OrderedDict()

for x in items:
    d.setdefault(key(x), x[:7] + [0])[7] += int(x[7])

print d.values()
```

---

```
[['A', 'a', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'd', 'C', 6], ['D', 'r', 's', 'E', 't', 'u', 'F', 4]]
```

Comment: +1 for the readable two-liner. A small explanation as to how everything works might be nice, as OP is a beginner.

Comment: thanks! Could you explain me how this works? I want to use it for a very similar problem where I have 2 separated lists (with sublist) to compare the sublists instead of only 1 list...